# LINQ - Inserts not working with "junction" table

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a "junction" table that stores a user's userID (same userID that is in aspnet_membership table) and an ID for a product.  I have added this table to a .dbml file.  I am trying to do an insert into the table using LINQ and it's failing.  Both fields in the junction table are set as primary keys, however, I do not have the aspnet_membership table in the .dbml file (nor do I have a relationship set between the two tables - it won't let me because the userID field in aspnet_membership is not a primary key).  Here's my code (I have used similar code in other locations without a problem so I suspect the .dbml configuration is the problem).  Any ideas why the inserts are failing?

```
bool success = false;
ASIStoreDataDataContext storeContext = new ASIStoreDataDataContext();
try
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        STOR_NewsletterUser newsSub = new STOR_NewsletterUser();
        newsSub.SNWS_NewsLetterID = newsletterID;
        newsSub.UserID = userID;
        storeContext.STOR_NewsletterUsers.InsertOnSubmit(newsSub);
        storeContext.SubmitChanges();
        success = true;
    }
}
catch { }

return success;
```

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Comment: @Arkain: Problem solved. @Sam: read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Your "junction" tables are more formally called "intersection" tables: just thought you'd want to know.

Comment: @Joel: I think you mean "Associative Entity"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, get rid of that try/catch block. Any random exception could be happenning in there, and you wouldn't know about it because you're eating the exception. Don't *ever* do that.

Now, maybe if you had posted the exception or other reason you believe the insert is failing, I could give you a better response. Instead, the best I can suggest is that you change your code as follows:

```
ASIStoreDataDataContext storeContext = new ASIStoreDataDataContext();
try
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return false;

    STOR_NewsletterUser newsSub = new STOR_NewsletterUser();
    newsSub.SNWS_NewsLetterID = newsletterID;
    newsSub.UserID = userID;
    storeContext.STOR_NewsletterUsers.InsertOnSubmit(newsSub);
    storeContext.SubmitChanges();
    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); // Or Debug.Print, or whatever
    throw;                            // Don't eat the exception
}
```

When you've got that done, edit your question to include the exception that is displayed. If no exception occurs, then edit your question to say what *does* happen that should not happen, or what does *not* happen that should happen.